# How can I have associations properly set in Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I am new to FactoryGirl. I come from the fixtures world.

I have the following two models:

```
class LevelOneSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :level_two_subjects, :inverse_of => :level_one_subject
  validates :name, :presence => true
end

class LevelTwoSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level_one_subject, :inverse_of => :level_two_subjects
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

And I would like to do something like the following in factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :level_one_subject, class: LevelOneSubject do
    factory :social_sciences do
      name "Social Sciences"
    end
  end

  factory :level_two_subject do
    factory :anthropology, class: LevelTwoSubject do
      name "Anthropology"
      association :level_one_subject, factory: social_sciences
    end

    factory :archaelogy, class: LevelTwoSubject do
      name "Archaelogy"
      association :level_one_subject, factory: social_sciences
    end
  end
end
```

Then when I use the factory in a spec like this:

```
it 'some factory test' do
  anthropology = create(:anthropology)
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :anthropology:Symbol
```

Can anybody help here?

If I do not set the association in factory, then I do not get this error, but I get the error that `level_one_subject_id` has to be present and only the following test code works:

```
it 'some factory test' do
  social_sciences = create(:social_sciences)
  anthropology = create(:anthropology, :level_one_subject_id => social_sciences.id)
end
```

But I really want to know why the factory with the association does not work. With Fixtures I had all this for nothing.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the `NoMethodError`? I think it will help to know what method is trying to call `name` on the `Symbol`. Add `--trace` to whatever command you run your tests with to get the full trace, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to group factories by a 'class factory', which is not how FactoryGirl works. It will deduce the ActiveRecord class from the factory name itself, if named appropriately. In case, your factory name is not the same as the class name, we need to explicitly specify the class name using class named parameter. This should work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :level_one_subject do # automatically deduces the class-name to be LevelOneSubject
        name "Social Sciences"
    end

    factory :anthropology, class: LevelTwoSubject do
        name "Anthropology"
        level_one_subject # associates object created by factory level_one_subject
    end

    factory :archaelogy, class: LevelTwoSubject do
        name "Archaelogy"
        level_one_subject # associates object created by factory level_one_subject
    end
end
```

Comment: Correct. And if I want to name the ```factory :level_one_subject``` as ```social_sciences``` I would have to put ```class: LevelOneSubject``` next to its name and then, in the level two subjects write ```association :level_one_subject, :factory => :social_sciences``` (instead of just ```level_one_subject```)